# Backslash for solving very big sparse matrix in Ax=b

Tags: matlab, code-generation, sparse-matrix, backslash

In my code at each time step sparse matrix `A` is built as follows:

```
1< DX <120000
```

`A = sparse(i,j,s,DX,DX,6*DX)`

```
b = (1,DX)
```

The problem that I am dealing is a sort of discretization problem. I have maximum 120000 nodes. Each of these nodes are having special charachters and I choose only the ones that meet my criteria. the number of these chosen ones is `DX` and is completely dependent on the physical process.

I am using backslash in `x = A\b`. But as the size of `A` could become quite big, the computational time rises drastically (more than 10e5 time steps are having (`DX > 6e4`).

As far as I know, backslash operation is already well optimized in MATLAB but I would like to know:

1. Would it make sense to use codegen and convert the code to C?
2. Does any one know an alternative method instead of backslash, so that the computational time decreases (maybe an iterative method)?

Comment: 1) No, Matlab will call precompiled highly optimized routines for performing sparse matrix factorizations. I think for most most inputs it will call SuiteSparse's QR factorization. For square matrices it follows [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/matlab/ref/mldivide_sparse.png) graph. So using codegen won't help. Codegen is mostly useful if you have code which uses a lot of `for` loops which are inefficient in M-code but fast in C/C++. In your case you're calling a built-in function so this won't do anything.

Comment: 2) Does your Matrix have any special structure? If it's square and diagonally dominant you can use Jacobi iterations which is very easy to code.

Comment: @jucestain: thank you for the answer! Unfortunately the matrix doesn't follow any structure. the values are randomly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

While `x = A\b` works well for many systems, you can run into memory issues causing slowdowns. Alternately, MATLAB has a number of built in functions for iteratively solving Ax=b for sparse matrices, such as `pcq()`, `bigcg()`, `cgs()`, etc.  See the [MATLAB Documentation on interative methods for solving systems of linear equations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html#brzoiix)